# How to get the last second of the month with datetime? Or last second of arbitrary date

Tags: php, datetime

Tried this:

```
$thismonth = new DateTime(dateReformat( 'Y-M' ));
$end       = $thismonth->modify('last day of this month 23:59');
```

got this: `2018-02-28 23:59` as expected.

Tried this:

```
$thismonth->modify('last day of this month 23:59:59');
```

got this: `2018-02-28 23:59` expected:  `2018-02-28 23:59:59`

I'm trying to make a query, where I dont miss anything from the last minute of the month.

Comment: [works for me](https://3v4l.org/Aj4YR).

Comment: isn't the last second of the month always `59` just saying...  It's kind of like the last hour is always `23`, and the last minute is always `59`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix nope. In the case of leap seconds it's occasionally 58 or 60/

Comment: @Sammitch - seems like a bug in the space time continuum to me.  Or is it a feature?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix it's just a bug in our perception of the space time continuum. The space time continuum doesn't care what second we think it is. ;)

Comment: @Doug maybe it would be simpler to select values less than the first day of next month for your query?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, yes, however the user sometimes picks the date, like 2018-02-15.  So, I would need something like "where tbl.date < 2018-02-15 23:59:59 "  Maybe I should edit my question a little.

Comment: @DougCassidy Take the date the user picks, add one day and then query for where the date is less than the result.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix It's a bug in the rotation of earth in that large enough geological and/or astrophysical events can speed up or slow down the rotation of the earth, requiring leap seconds to keep midnight actually at midnight. This, coupled with certain incorrect assumptions people make about "X period of time being exactly Y" lead to *programming* bugs that cause systems to behave in unpredictable ways during leap years/days/seconds.

Comment: @Sammitch - Great Point!

Answer (score 0):

As @salathe mentioned in comment

In order to get seconds, You must provide it in format

```
  echo $thismonth->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // note the "s"
```

Or as you requested in your comment

> yes, however the user sometimes picks the date, like 2018-02-15. So, I
>   would need something like "where tbl.date < 2018-02-15 23:59:59 "
>   Maybe I should edit my question a little.

Use where clause in sql queries like this

```
WHERE date(tbl.date) <= '2018-02-15'
```